# Capistrano and Bitbucket permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, digital-ocean

I'm trying to set up capistrano with my Rails app and hosting using digitalocean.

I have a Ubuntu server running unicorn and nginx.

My capistrano deploy keeps failing at this stage:

```
DEBUG [08cab5b3] Command: cd /home/rails/automata && (     GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/automata/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git     clone --mirror git@bitbucket.org:automata_tech/staging.git     /home/rails/automata/repo )
DEBUG [08cab5b3]        Cloning into bare repository     '/home/rails/automata/repo'...
DEBUG [08cab5b3]        /home/rails/automata/repo: Permission denied
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as     deployer@178.62.4.140: git exit status: 1
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Cloning into bare repository    '/home/rails/automata/repo'...
/home/rails/automata/repo: Permission denied

SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 1
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Cloning into bare repository    '/home/rails/automata/repo'...
/home/rails/automata/repo: Permission denied

Tasks: TOP => git:create_release => git:update => git:clone
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as     deployer@178.62.4.140: git exit status: 1
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Cloning into bare repository    '/home/rails/automata/repo'...
/home/rails/automata/repo: Permission denied
```

I have generated a ssh key on the server and added it to my bitbucket account.

If I ssh into the server and git clone the repo, that works fine.

Running ssh -T git@bitbucket.org on the server returns:

```
 logged in as company.

 You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

staging.rb :

```
set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: true,
  auth_methods: %w(publickey)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message shows a `permission denied` error when trying to create the directory `/home/rails/automata/repo`. In other words, your deployer user doesn't have the necessary file permissions. It has nothing to do with your SSH key or Bitbucket.

Just make sure that `/home/rails/automata` exists and is owned by `deployer`. You may need to use `sudo` or log in as `root` to do this.

```
mkdir -p /home/rails/automata
chown deployer /home/rails/automata
```

BTW, I'm not sure placing your app inside `/home/rails` makes sense. If you are using `deployer` to deploy (and thus be the owner of) your app, wouldn't it make more sense to put it in `/home/deployer`? Or in a "neutral" location like `/var/www/automata` (as Capistrano suggests by default)?

Comment: Thanks, solved allot of issues changing the directory to /home/deployer.

Answer (score 0):

In your config/deploy/production.rb (or staging.rb), you need to enable ssh agent forwarding.

You can do this by changing your server file to include `forward_agent: true`.

Here's an example:

```
server 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
  user: 'deploy',
  roles: %w{web app db},
  ssh_options: {
    forward_agent: true,
    auth_methods: %w(publickey)
  }
```

Comment: FYI, `forward_agent` is set to true by default in Capistrano, so you shouldn't need to set it yourself. https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/blob/v1.8.0/lib/sshkit/host.rb#L86

Comment: @AdamBishti is the permission error with git, or with the folder? Can you give the output of this command: `ls -lah /home/rails/automata`